# Counter in Matlab-mex code does not stop after predetermined iterations

Tags: matlab, openmp, mex

I am running a loop in mex file from Matlab using OpenMP, and it does not stop after the predetermined number of iterations is reached.

I compile the file with this command:

```
mex myfile.c CFLAGS= \$CFLAGS -fopenmp LDFLAGS=\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp
```

and my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>\n'
#include "mex.h"\n'
#include "omp.h"\n'

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
    int i;
    int numthreads = 8;
    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) num_threads(numthreads) private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Hello world number %d from omp thread %d\n", i, tid);
    }
}
```

I expected to get 'Hello world 0...' through 'Hello world 19...', just one of each, in whatever order. Instead they keep repeating indefinitely.

```
Hello world number 0 from omp thread 0
Hello world number 1 from omp thread 0
Hello world number 2 from omp thread 0
Hello world number 3 from omp thread 1
Hello world number 4 from omp thread 1
Hello world number 5 from omp thread 1
Hello world number 12 from omp thread 4
Hello world number 13 from omp thread 4
Hello world number 16 from omp thread 6
Hello world number 17 from omp thread 6
Hello world number 18 from omp thread 7
Hello world number 19 from omp thread 7
Hello world number 6 from omp thread 2
Hello world number 7 from omp thread 2
Hello world number 8 from omp thread 2
Hello world number 8 from omp thread 2
Hello world number 9 from omp thread 3
Hello world number 10 from omp thread 3
Hello world number 11 from omp thread 3
Hello world number 14 from omp thread 5
Hello world number 15 from omp thread 5
Hello world number 0 from omp thread 0
Hello world number 1 from omp thread 0
Hello world number 2 from omp thread 0
Hello world number 12 from omp thread 4
Hello world number 13 from omp thread 4
```

Comment: Are you saying that you get 'Hello world number 20' and 'Hello world number 21'? Because I didn't see it in your block of the result.

Comment: I expected to get 'Hello world 0...' through 'Hello world 19...', just one of each, in whatever order. Instead they keep repeating indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is translated to `mexPrintf`, which causes the given formatted string to be displayed in the MATLAB command window. You are not using the C library `printf` here. `mex.h` declares a macro to make this translation.

The MATLAB MEX interface is not thread-safe. You cannot call these functions from any thread except the main one.

Thus, you are likely hitting some undefined behavior caused by calling `mexPrintf` from multiple threads.

As a workaround, consider writing to a file. `fprintf` will not be replaced by the MEX interface, but you cannot use it to write to the MATLAB command window.